# Is the integral closure of an integral domain a dedekind domain?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I am reading through Milne's number theory notes, and he shows that the ring of integers of a field is a dedekind domain. He also shows that the integral closure of a dedekind domain A in a finite separable extension of Frac(A) is a dedekind domain. But what if we only know that A is an integral domain? Can we still conclude that its integral closure is a dedekind domain? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Dedekind domains must be one-dimensional, so here is an easy counter-example: the integral closure of $A=\mathbb C[x,y]\subset\mathbb C(x,y)$ is itself, which is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: More explicitly: the ideal $xA$ of $A$ is a nonzero prime ideal but not maximal, as e.g. it's contained in the ideal $xA + yA$.